# Можно ли заставить работать быстрее базу SqLite

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite

В своем работающем проекте, имел локальную базу данных, данные записывались в базу быстро, перешел на sqlite. Все прекрасно до тех пор пока не нужно записать в базу более 1000 записей. Само приложении работает с базой без нареканий, но вот запись в базу происходит медленно. Вопрос, можно ли как то увеличить скорость?
 В базу записываю таким методом

```
public void InsertTABLECHANGEHISTORY(String connectionString, String[] values)
{
    using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString))
    {
        using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            //SET IDENTITY_INSERT TESTTYPES ON SET IDENTITY_INSERT TESTTYPES OFF
            command.CommandText = @" INSERT INTO TABLECHANGEHISTORY(TABLENAME, MODIFIEDDATE) VALUES(@a, @b)";
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", values[0]);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b", DateTime.Parse(values[1]));
            connection.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Каждый массив это строка. Тот же самый вариант с  LocalDB работает быстрее. Вопрос где искать причину тормозов. Про  AddWithValue знаю что так лучше не делать, но сейчас это эксперимент.  В режиме отладки данные пишутся в базу медленно, 6-7 минут и в базе 15700 строк.

P.S. Подсказали про  пакет запросов. Так ли я его понял, вот сам запрос, который выполняет три вставки.

```
INSERT INTO TABLECHANGEHISTORY(TABLENAME, MODIFIEDDATE) VALUES(@a,@b),(@b,@c),(@d,@e)
```

Так ли?

Comment: Ну это меньше 30 миллисекунд на запись - нормальная скорость. Надо быстрее - формируйте пакеты по несколько записей за запрос.

Comment: @Akina Спасибо за ответ. а как это можно сформировать такой пакет? Я имею ввиду пример подскажите для наглядности?

Comment: `INSERT INTO tablename (fieldset) VALUES (valueset1), (valueset2), ... (valuesetN);`. Старайтесь при этом не выскочить за предел допустимой (настройками сервера) длины запроса.

Comment: @Akina А мой запрос разве не делает тоже самое?

Comment: То же, но по одной записи. То есть для КАЖДОЙ записи сервер выполняет парсинг запроса и его выполнение, да плюс передачи туда-сюда. Собрав кучу данных в один запрос, Вы избавитесь от значительной части повторяющихся операций. Сейчас основное время тратится не на запись данных в таблицу, а именно на сопутствующие операции. Что быстрее - положить на соседний стол всю папку, или перекладывать её по одному листочку?

Comment: @Akina Да согласен с Вами, на вход метода подается массив данных, который в свою очередь берется из переменной в форыче. Тогда надо переделывать сам цикл в котором я распарсиваю текстовые строчки до состояния массива. который и подается на вход метода, который я написал в вопросе. Правда я не совсем понял сам синтаксис таких запросов , в котором несколько запросов.

Comment: Оберните вставку в одну транзакцию. [faq](https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q19)

Comment: *синтаксис таких запросов , в котором несколько запросов* Запрос-то один. Просто блоков данных в нём несколько, и вставляет он сразу несколько записей.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Спасибо за ответ, а пример как обернуть в транзакцию можно где то увидеть? Я сними не работал. Понятие имею что  это.

Comment: @Akina Спасибо попробую.

Comment: @Akina Я подправил мой вопрос, скажите правильно ли я понял вас с точки зрения синтаксиса?

Comment: Я как-то для одного спора набросал [код](https://pastebin.com/KfFKnTB9) вставки в транзакции. Сто тысяч инсёртов в секунду. | Возможно, также будет полезно включить [pooling](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlite-net-provider/with-connection-pooling/)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Спасибо

Comment: И хотел узнать как транзакция влияет на скорость?

Comment: *правильно ли я понял вас с точки зрения синтаксиса?* Нет. Я же показал шаблон правильного синтаксиса - откуда Вы нарожали пачку слов VALUES и куда дели запятые?

Comment: @Akina Подправил в вопросе.

Comment: Вы пытаетесь написать ответ в вопросе, не надо так делать. У вас был один вопрос, а теперь уже другой, написанный поверх первого.

Comment: @AK SO так и советует делать. А иногда и вынуждает. Например, если уже заблокирована возможность создавать вопросы, то правила ресурса советуют заменять старые вопросы на новые что бы создать себе плюсцов и выйти из минуса что бы снова появилась возможность создавать новые. Но вообще да, так делать не нужно... Тем более если есть возможность этот вопрос закрыть и создать новый.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Спасибо за подсказку про транзакции и пуллинг, летает теперь все так ,как я не ожидал.

Comment: @Akina Спасибо за ценный совет про пакет запросов.